# Solution of $x^{x^x}=3$

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, exponential-function, problem-solving

Is it possible to analytically solve the expression $x^{x^x}=3$?

And how to solve this problem numerically?

Simply testing some results, I found that $\sqrt{2.6}<x<\sqrt{2.7}$. What matches the result provided by [Elliot G](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/252495/elliot-g) in the comments.

But in addition to a numerical solution, like the technique posted by [glowstonetrees](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3708827/680679), is it possible to find a "closed" formula for the solution of this problem?

Comment: If you just want a numerical answer, Mathematica gives one real solution with the first several digits as $1.63507847463637524589975719878750088812\ldots$. It was only able to estimate this over the reals though.

Comment: @ElliotG I tried to use it and I couldn't (I don't know how to use it very well), could you share the code you used?
But in reality I would like to know if it is possible to solve in an analytical way, to obtain a "closed form" for the solution.

Comment: I'm not sure how to evaluate without Mathematica, but the code was `NSolve[x^x^x == 3, x, Reals, WorkingPrecision -> 10]`

Comment: You should never edit your question after an extended period of time to make a well-crafted answer irrelevant. It’s very disrespectful to the user who spent time and energy in an effort to help you!

Comment: [Since $x^{x^x}$ is one to one on the interval $(0,\infty)$ solve for $x$ if $x^{x^x} = y$ and $y>0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3291993/318073)

Comment: The best the simple lookup from the [Inverse Symbolic Calculator](http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/cgi-bin/isc/lookup?number=1.635078474636375245&lookup_type=simple) could find, is only correct for first $7$ decimal places: (where $C$ is Catalan's constant)

$$
x\approx Ce^{-\pi/2}+e^{1/e}
$$

Using [wolfam alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1.635078474636375245899757198787500888123982192768146193517444562896762462316303676209), the following is correct for first $18$ decimal places:

$$
x\approx \frac{1}{96} (-85 C + 52 - 74 \pi - 116 \pi^2 + 745 \pi \log(2) - 18 \pi \log(3))
$$

Answer (score 6):

Quite sure you can't solve this analytically.

On the other hand, there are many numerical methods for solving $f(x)=0$. For example, Newton's method gives the sequence of iterates

$$x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$

for any starting guess $x_0$ that is close enough to the desired solution.

In your case, you would have

$$f(x) = x^{x^x}-3 \qquad \qquad f'(x) = x^{x^x}x^x\bigg( \frac 1x + \ln (x) \big(1+\ln(x)\big)\bigg)$$

So for example you could run a for-loop

\begin{align}
& x_0 = 1 \\
& \text{for } n = 0,1,2,\dots \\
& \; \; \; \; \; x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{x_n^{x_n^{x_n}}-3}{x_n^{x_n^{x_n}}x_n^{x_n}\Big( \frac {1}{x_n} + \ln (x_n) \big(1+\ln(x_n)\big)\Big)} \\
& \text{end}
\end{align}

Comment: In my opinion, everything after the first sentence is irrelevant to *this* question. The OP didn’t have a problem getting a stellar approximation and doesn’t seem to be interested in the process. It almost comes across as “I need some fluff in here so I can get upvotes.” I’m more interested in **why** you’re “Quite sure you can’t solve this analytically.” Unless you have a justification as to how mentioning Newton’s method and designing a for-loop has remotely anything to do with finding a closed-form solution, I think I’ll downvote.

Comment: The OP did one of the supposedly forbidden thing of editing the question after I posted my answer. Originally, the second part of his question asked "can this be solved using numerical methods", in which case I suggested Newton's method as an example.

Comment: +1 I see that now! I will flag the question for moderator intervention and ask for a rollback of the edits. I also left a comment for the OP.

Comment: The OP put “how to solve this problem numerically?” back in the body of the post.

Answer (score 1):

For sure, a numerical solution could always be obtained using, as already suggested in comments, Newton method which will be the simplest.

You just need to reformulate the problem as : find the zero of function
$$f(x)=x^{x^x}-3$$ The problem is that the function is so stiff that, if you do not have a good estimate, many iterations could be required. For example, let us start with $x_0=2$ which looks to be very close to the solution. The iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 2.0000000 \\
 1 & 1.8786299 \\
 2 & 1.7574536 \\
 3 & 1.6696436 \\
 4 & 1.6380522 \\
 5 & 1.6351011 \\
 6 & 1.6350785
\end{array}
\right)$$

Trying to make the problem more linear, trying with
$$g(x)=\log(x^{x^x})-\log(3)$$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 2.0000000 \\
 1 & 1.7499438 \\
 2 & 1.6481903 \\
 3 & 1.6352591 \\
 4 & 1.6350785
\end{array}
\right)$$ One more step in the same direction with
$$h(x)=\log(\log(x^{x^x}))-\log(\log(3))$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 2.0000000 \\
 1 & 1.6165932 \\
 2 & 1.6349681 \\
 3 & 1.6350785
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: @glowstonetrees already suggested Newton’s method for a numerical solution

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish yes but without the log trick...

Comment: @pluton I do not see the "trick" here - is it that there are less steps? But there are extra calculations at each step, so does it become less computation-demanding?

Comment: I think what @Claude Leibovici is trying to say is that we can rewrite the equation as $$x^{x^x}=3\implies x^x\ln(x)=\ln(3)$$ and apply Newton's method on $$f(x)=x^x\ln(x)-\ln(3)$$ instead. This achieves faster convergence because the function is less steep around the root. Thus, by doing the one extra step of calculating $\ln(3)$ at the beginning, you save yourself many steps afterwards because it converges quicker.

Comment: @glowstonetrees Plus an additional $ln$ at each step, right?

Comment: @DávidLaczkó Computing $a^b$ usually uses logarithms *and* an exponential function, so this would actually be one exponential function computed less per iteration.